# jsPDF - addHTML() to center of pdf page?

Tags: jspdf

How to convert html element into pdf and set it at the center of the page.

[image]

It is coming at the left top corner of the pdf page

Answer (score 0):

Its not the exact solution but i think it will work . so it will create the pdf page with exact height and width of the html div

```
const invoiceSection = $("#customer_invoice_bill");

let invoiceName = invoiceSection.data("invoiceName");

var pdfConf = {
    pagesplit: true,
    background: "#fff",
};
var pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", [
    invoiceSection.height() + 100,
    invoiceSection.width(),
]);
pdf.addHTML(invoiceSection, pdfConf, function () {
    pdf.save(`${invoiceName}.pdf`);
});
```

adding height and width of html div to the jsPDF() parameter works

```
new jsPDF("p", "pt", [
  invoiceSection.height() + 100,  ------ > ** adding html div height **
  invoiceSection.width(), -------- > ** adding html div width **
]);
```